# CSS class won't change html output

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

All I am trying to do is centre a p element on a web page with a css class I made,

```
.buttons_editdelete{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
font-size:xx-large
}
```

but this does not work. In fact I put the font-size in as a test and that is not working either.

```
<p class="buttons_editdelete">test</p>
```

That is my html element. The class is coming up from intellisense so it is being included, but there is no difference on my web page. 
I have even tried adding in this class to the bootstrap.css file but it still has no effect. If I use any class from bootstrap which was already there then they do effect the web page.

I really can't understand why this is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `text-align: center;`

Comment: This also does not work. I'm sure it should, but the problem lies elsewhere with my css class just having no effect for some reason.

Comment: A paragraph tag is a blocked element that takes up a whole line on the screen. Your css is centering the paragraph element but it can't be anymore centered than it already is. Try using `text-align` instead or an equivalent

Comment: if you want to center with margins use margin: 0 auto; ^ text-align: center should do it for you though

Comment: Post a complete code example please so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: I managed to get it working by using the text-center class in bootstrap. But strangely if i recreate that class exactly (which just has text-align in it), but with a different name, and place it right below in the same file that class will not work. I am actually baffled as to how that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bootstrap way to handle it would be to add the class `text-center`to the `<p>` As in:

```
<p class="buttons_editdelete text-center">test</p>
```

See [**Bootstrap Text Alignment Docs**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment)

Comment: I managed to get it working by using the text-center class in bootstrap. But strangely if i recreate that class exactly (which just has text-align: center in it), but with a different name, and place it right below in the same file, that class will not work. I don't understand how that is happening

Comment: Strange...without a working example it's hard to say what is overriding your added style. Glad you got it working with bootstraps class though :)

Answer (score 3):

You can either do:

```
.buttons_editdelete {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size:xx-large;
  display: table; 
}
```

**Output:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgQrbb

or

```
.buttons_editdelete {
  text-align:center;
  font-size:xx-large;
}
```

**Output:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvaRMR

Both will center your text.

Answer (score 1):

Margin won't centre the text but it will center the `<p>`.

To centre the text use `p {text-align: center;}`

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the p tag inside another block level element and using margin: 0 auto;

```
<div class="content">
  <p class="buttons_editdelete">
  </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50ch
}
```

Alternatively, you could use text-align:center on your paragraph element like this:

```
p.buttons_editdelete {
  text-align:center;
}
```

Also - try giving the element a specific width.

Comment: I managed to get it working by using the text-center class in bootstrap. But strangely if i recreate that class exactly (which just has text-align: center in it), but with a different name, and place it right below in the same file that class will not work. I don't understand how that is happening.

Comment: If it's working with the bootstrap text-center class then I would just use that and move on to your next task :)